# Control manually drawn have weird font

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, controls

Long story short, I'm drawing a control (ex.: A button) in a Bitmap in a way similar to the following:

```
using (Bitmap controlBitmap = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height))
{
    using (Graphics controlGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(controlBitmap))
    {
        PaintEventArgs args = new PaintEventArgs(controlGraphic, control.ClientRectangle);

        MethodInfo info = control.GetType().GetMethod("OnPaintBackground", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        info.Invoke(control, new object[] { args });
        info = control.GetType().GetMethod("OnPaint", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        info.Invoke(control, new object[] { args });

        graphic.DrawImage(controlBitmap, control.Left, control.Top);
    }
}
```

And while all the controls are correctly drawn, the only thing that is not is the text.

[image: Fat or corrupted text?]

I kinda reached the limit of my knowledge on how controls behave. I don't know why the text is the only part that is not properly drawn.

What am I missing to make the font appear correctly?

Comment: Why are you invoking the methods via reflection? Are you not subclassing the control and drawing it yourself?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I'm not overriding any existing control, I'm using existing control inside a different rendering context. I don't have the code on how "Button" is drawn, and even if I had, it would be pointless; I'm not re-writing the whole .NET collection of controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, the text isn't getting anti-aliased properly, blending from black to black.  As though the background is transparent.  No idea why.  Just don't do it this way, take advantage of Control.DrawToBitmap():

```
    using (Bitmap controlBitmap = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height)) 
    using (Graphics controlGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(controlBitmap)) {
        control.DrawToBitmap(controlBitmap, control.DisplayRectangle);
        graphic.DrawImage(controlBitmap, control.Left, control.Top);
    }
```

Comment: And one more method to learn; I didn't know the existance of 'DrawToBitmap'. I'm somehow surprised it draws it properly while calling the 'OnPaint' and 'OnPaintBackground' does not. Something is obviously setup in background. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just found out that the `DrawToBitmap` offers me another challenge. The control drawn this way automatically request the background form to be drawn too. The weird side effect is, if a control has some transparency, the resulted bitmap has none and is already pre-blended with the background. In other word, every pixel returned by this method always have their alpha at 255. I was wondering if you had any idea how to draw a control while leaving the background form alone.

Comment: I'd guess you'll want to pass the PixelFormat argument to the Bitmap constructor to get a 32bppArgb bitmap.  You can't "leave the form alone", it must draw itself into the bitmap to provide the background pixels.

Comment: My bitmap is already in 32bppArgb. The pixels returned by `DrawToBitmap`are always 255 except for fully transparent one which shows up as (0, 0, 0, 0). If the background is also transparent, `DrawToBitmap` ignores that alpha value and only pull the color from the background. I was hoping that method would draw only the control. What would happen if a control had no parent and no form?

Comment: I don't know.  Clearly you'll have to click the Ask Question button and explain the problem in detail.